# Understanding Excel formulae- Date difference mixed with integer

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel formulae like

```
=IF(C4="","",(IF(C4<B1-211,"R",10)))
```

C4 is a cell for which it is applicable

C4 contains a **date time**, B1 also contains a **date time**

But what is the role if **211** i am not getting.

Any help is highly appreciated

**EDIT**
Example:

C4 = 11/15/2011

B1 = 06/09/2012

I am getting value of 10

Comment: What is the Excel file used for?

Comment: This is an excel file made in Excel 2010. I am confused about this e.g. A>B -211? what is True - 211

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel stores dates as number of days since Jan-1-0000. You can actually see this: just `Clear Format` on any date cell.
Therefore, any date minus 1 returns the day before.
In your case, if C4 is before (B1-211 days) then return "R", else display 10.
Does not seem too clean !-/